# Unexpected '=' in R when adding header for API connection

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to access an API using the R code supplied by the API developer.

```
response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers(x_rapidapi-key = 
'9f70422103msh84418664e8696a3p1e3243jsndda4f4f72b69', x_rapidapi-host = 'call-of-duty-modern-
warfare.p.rapidapi.com', '), content_type("application/octet-stream"))
```

But i get an error regarding an unexpected '=' on add_headers, i'm running the code in RStudio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @MrFlick I **strongly** discourage the practice of using straight quotes to escape non-syntactic names. Please use backticks. Even the R documentation says to prefer them. The fact that R even allows straight quotes here, and invites confusion between names and strings, is a deep flaw in the language that should be deprecated and removed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Are they treated differently in the parser? This seems much more balanced to me: `x <- list("a-b"=4); x[["a-b"]]`. But I understand your point.

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah, they’re treated differently by the parser (`"foo"` literally *is a character literal*), but identically during evaluation in certain contexts (= in all contexts where only a name is valid, and not a character string). As for your example, `[[` performs standard evaluation, `$` doesn’t — and it’s very unusual to write `x$"name"`. So the balance argument here can also be inverted, to argue that `x = list(name = 4)` is more balanced because it mirrors the usage via `x$name`.

Comment: Hello, is there a typo in the code you posted? The quotes don't seem balanced at this argument: `x_rapidapi-host = 'call-of-duty-modern-warfare.p.rapidapi.com', '` . Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

there are some mistakes in the R snippets provided by RapidAPI. Perhaps you already figure it out but I will add here the corrected snippet:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "YOUR_URL_WITH_ENDPOINT"

response <- VERB("GET", url, 
                 add_headers("X-RapidAPI-Key" = 'YOUR_API_KEY'), 
                 content_type("application/octet-stream"),
                 encode = 'json')

Robject <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(response, "text"))
head(Robject$response)
```

Three things to notice:

1. in the add_header function there is an extra ' that should be removed.
2. the correct header field should be X-RapidAPI-Key not x_rapidapi-key
3. as spotted by @MrFlick, you need to put the headers field in quotations.